# register_post_type does not work

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a problem with a register_post_type and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I created a function:

```
    /* Início da função de Post personalizado */
function createbdposttype() {
    register_post_type( 'bd',
    // Opções
    array(
      'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'faqs' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'Faqs' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => false,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faqs'),
     )
    );
}
// Conectando nossa função à configuração do tema
    add_action( 'init', 'createbdposttype' );
/* Fim da função de Post personalizado */
```

Well, according to the documentation you should create a single-**bd**.php

where **bd** would be my `register_post_type`

Well, when I create a custom post that I'm going to view, it only appears a 404 page what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you refreshed your permalinks settings? Go to _Settings > Permalinks_ and save.

Comment: Thank you very much.